# Why the tool tip shows the control type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, tooltip

I'm trying to show some text in the tool tip. I search for some solutions on the internet, but it doesn't work:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ResultText">
  <TextBlock.ToolTip>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ResultToolTip" />
  </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Code:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(ResultText, TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("MyPath")
{
  Source = myObject,
  StringFormat = "MyFormat"
});

BindingOperations.SetBinding(ResultToolTip, TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("MyPath")
{
  Source = myObject,
  StringFormat = "MyFormat"
});
```

This approach works for normal `TextBlock`, but for tooltip it's like:

[image: Tool tip shows type name]

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way (consider if you need change notification for the `MyPath`, the `MyObject` class should inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject { MyPath = "value" };

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(ResultText, TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("MyPath")
        {
        Source = myObject,
        StringFormat = "MyFormat"
        });

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(ResultToolTip, TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("MyPath")
        {
        Source = myObject,
        StringFormat = "MyFormat"
        });
    }

}

class MyObject
{
    private string _myPath;

    public string MyPath
    {
        get { return _myPath; }
        set { _myPath = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is an acceptable answer, but you should normally use bindings from XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ResultText" Text="{Binding Source=TextBlockText}">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ResultToolTip" Text="{Binding Source=TooltipText}"/>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

And then just make two properties in the C# code, that are uses the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface funcionality.

You could have a reason not to do it this way though